# Android Java Splash Screen code

Tags: java, android, animation

Here's my android splash screen. I am trying to figure out a better way to write it. It just moves the logo up to the center of the screen. It's my third time creating a splash screen for an android app. I am just trying to figure out the best way to write more optimized code.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;

final public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final static int timeout = 3000;
    final static Handler handler = new Handler();
    static ImageView logo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        logo = findViewById(R.id.companylogo);
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Splash.this, R.anim.myanim);
        logo.startAnimation(animation);

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent splashscreen = new Intent(Splash.this, Home.class);
                startActivity(splashscreen);
            }

        }, timeout);

    }




}
```

Answer (score 4):

This code looks reasonably clean and seems to accomplish what it's intended to do.
Some minor nitpicks can still be improved here and there:

- You're not consistent in visibility modifier ordering between class declaration and member declarations. It should either be `public final class` or `final private static int timeout`.
  Most Java conventions that I've seen default to the `public static final` ordering.
- `handler` and `logo` are currently package-private. It's very unusual for that visibility to be necessary and I think setting these to `private` if at all possible would be better. (I'm not recommending `protected`, because the class can not be extended.)
- `static final` members are usually named in `SNAKE_CAPS` (also known as shout-case).
- the id `companylogo` might be better off named `companyLogo` to follow camel case conventions.
- `myanimation` doesn't tell us anything about the animation. A better name would be `splashScreenAnimation` or `logoAnimation`